# Getting error "expecting POST /_api/cursor" from ArangoDB.js

Tags: node.js, arangodb

If I try to get records greater than 1,000, I get the "expecting POST /_api/cursor" error when I call the cursor.all() method in ArangoDB.js.

Here is my installation:
ArangoDB version 3.7.6
ArangoDB.js versioin 8.6.0
Node.js version 18.14.0

To replicate:

```
const Database = require( 'arangojs' ).Database;
let db = new Database({
   url: 'HTTP://127.0.0.1:8529',
   databaseName: 'TEST',
   auth: { username: 'root', password: 'test' }
});
let cursor = await db.query( 'FOR doc1 IN FOICU RETURN { "CU_NAME": doc1.CU_NAME }' );
let result = await cursor.all();
return result;
```

If I add 'LIMIT 100' to the query, everything works as expected.  If I add 'LIMIT 1001' or anything over 1,000 I get the error.

I want to implement paging but the cursor fails when I even call the cursor.fullCount().
Any ideas what I can try?

My TEST database, collection: FOICU has 100,000 records with only one attribute called CU_NAME
I can use the web interface and get all the records so I can dump to a file, but I can't get all the records using the ArangoDB.js driver.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting.  The LIMIT should be 1000.  I’ve tried other databases and different collections but all have the same result.

Comment: The problem started in version 8.4.0 of the Arango Javascript driver.  Version 8.3.0 works.  I posted an issue under the official Javascript driver repository (https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs) awaiting for a fix.